# Setting networkD3 Node Size with vector of weights

Tags: r, tree, data-visualization, networkd3

I'm trying to use `data.tree` and `NetworkD3` in R to create a tree representation of a file system where the nodes of the graph are weighted by file size.

```
library(data.tree)
library(networkD3)

repo <- Node$new("Repository")
git <- repo$AddChild(".git")
prod <- repo$AddChild("Production")
exp <- repo$AddChild("Experimental")

repo$size <- 866000
git$size <- 661000
prod$size <- 153000
exp$size <- 48000
```

I can get a vector of these sizes using Get, so that

```
sizes <- repo$Get("size")
```

But when I try to put it all together, I'm not sure how to include this weight information in the network visualization step. Trying to do something like this...

```
reponet <- ToDataFrameNetwork(repo,"repo")
net <- forceNetwork(reponet, Nodesize = repo$Get("size"))
```

to no avail. Basically I'm trying to do what Julia Silge did in this great [SO blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2017/10/03/mapping-ecosystems-software-development/). Does anyone know how to set this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the help file for `forceNetwork`... there are numerous, mandatory parameters that you have not set.

You can use `simpleNetwork` to plot a network with just a links data frame like you have, but it doesn't allow you to control the node size... for example...

```
simpleNetwork(reponet)
```

To control the node size, you need to use `forceNetwork`, but it requires a links data frame and a nodes data frame. You could build the nodes data frame from the `sizes` object you created, and then adjust the source and target IDs in your links data frame to match the indexes of the appropriate node in your nodes data frame (0 indexed because it's sent to JavaScript)... for example...

```
nodesdf <- data.frame(name = names(sizes), nodesize = sizes / 10000, group = 1)

reponet$from <- match(reponet$from, nodesdf$name) - 1
reponet$to <- match(reponet$to, nodesdf$name) - 1

forceNetwork(reponet, Nodes = nodesdf, Source = "from", Target = "to", 
             NodeID = "name", Group = "group", Nodesize = "nodesize")
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth explanation. This worked immediately. Excited to look at more ways to customize.